# Is this JS library using openssl genrsa -rand improperly?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, entropy, openssl

[pem](https://github.com/andris9/pem), a JS wrapper around openssl, [has the following code in it](https://github.com/andris9/pem/blob/2cd2135f6b5f9c8414147ebe991ef1345fd5e6cf/lib/pem.js#L38-L42):

```
var params = ['genrsa',
    '-rand',
    '/var/log/mail:/var/log/messages',
    keyBitsize
];
```

Am I correct in thinking that that is an improper usage of the `-rand` option (poor entropy = bad seed for random number generator)?

Cause this dude [just closed the issue thinking it's OK](https://github.com/andris9/pem/issues/46), and if he's wrong, it'd be nice if someone could explain in better detail than I can why what he is doing is unsafe.

If I'm mistaken and it is safe, I'd be curious to hear why.

Thanks Cryptography StackExchange!

Answer (score 4):

I ran the command under `dtruss` on OSX, with it pointing to a static file. Even then, it *appears* to use this as an additional source of randomness to `/dev/urandom`.

It's distasteful and almost certainly pointless. But assuming it only mixes the data into an already cryptographically-secure source of randomness, it's not actively harmful. That said, I can only see the syscalls being made — it's possible this is not what's happening at all under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I'm not marking your answer as correct since it's not definitive, but I gave ya an upvote for investigating! Thank you! :)